# Открытие меню автоматически после запуска приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Если это вообще возможно

меню прописано так в MainActivity

```
drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withToolbar(mToolbar)
        .withSelectedItem(1)
        .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
        .addDrawerItems(
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.Home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.News).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_newspaper),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName("About").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question_circle),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4).withName("Open Source").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github_square),
            new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5).withName("Rate on Google Play").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_thumbs_up)
        )
        .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
        .build();
drawer.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                return true;
            case 2:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, NewsListActivity.class));
                return true;
            case 3:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                startActivity(new Intent(context, AboutTheDevActivity.class));
                return true;
            case 4:
                drawer.closeDrawer();
                drawer.setSelection(1);
                libsBuilder.start(context);
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Похоже, вы используете какую-то библиотеку для NavigationDrawer. Если да - укажите какую, дайте ссылку на исходники оной. По сути вопроса - по идее, в либе должен быть способ программного открытия. Надо его в onCreate активити вызвать. Если же делать стандартными средствами, без либы, то можно просто в разметке, вроде, gravity выставить и оно будет по умолчанию открыто, но это не точно.

Comment: наверно эта implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar") . Я только учусь, эксперементирую над одним проектом

Comment: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: По идее там должен быть метод типа `drawer.openDrawer()` - попробуйте его вызвать.